# Would a firepro m4000 work on 16.04

Tags: external-monitor, 16.04, gpu-driver

I have a laptop with a firepro M4000 graphics card. On 15.10, I've had no problems, but when I tried 16.04 (at various stages, the last time was a week ago), I can only get my laptop monitor to work and the external display is not detected.

I've read that fglrx is no longer available on 16.04, and that the firepro m4000 is not supported by the open source drivers. Can anybody confirm?

Will I ever be able to get this set-up to work properly on 16.04?